# style equalTo method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to apply some css rules to the equalTo method?

Ok..so I made it like this: to run this script you need some css file which is this:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css

I copied the css code from the file, made the specific changes and now is working.

```
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: "required",
    remail: {
      equalTo: "#email"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This should work. What's the issue?

Comment: I know it's working but I need to apply some css rules on the messages..i would want the messages to be in the rght of the textbox not on the left

Comment: Are you looking for the `errorPlacement` option?

Answer (score -1):

You can directly assign the rule directly to the equalTo tag
$("#password").css("background-color","red")